# How to add together a racket scheme list

Tags: list, scheme, racket, addition

New to Racket Scheme and attempting to add together the contents of a defined list. I am to add together the list individually such as the totals of each individual list and then the totals of all of the list together.

So far what i have is the defined list and what i believe to be an inital addition of the totals of the list but it appears that nothing is being sum'd together. How can i add together all of the values in this list and all the list individually as well?

**CODE**

```
#lang racket
(define team '(("Emp1" (57 57 80 47 68 56 84 65))
               ("Emp2" (57 69 57 84 87 71 77 69 61 48))
               ("Emp3" (46 47 61 65 81 64 40 77 51 78))
               ("Emp4" (70 68 89 41))
               ("Emp5" (45 48 74 83 40 44 70 85 98 86))
               ))

(define (getEmpTotals team)
  (if (empty? team) 0
      (+ (first team)(getEmpTotals(rest team)))))
```

**Function to Implement**

```
(getTeamTotal team)
```

**Desired Output**

```
(("Emp1" 514) ("Emp2" 680) ("Emp3" 610) ("Emp4" 268) ("Emp5" 673))

2745
```

Comment: Seems a little vague. Are you looking for `(apply + (cadar team)) ; ==> 514` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `(first team)` is extracting a the list `("Emp1" (57 57 80 47 68 56 84 65))`, which you can't use `+` on.

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit)

;; A Team is a [Listof [list String [Listof Number]]]
;; or
;; A Team is a [Listof Emp]
;; An Emp is a [list String [Listof Number]]

(define team '(("Emp1" (57 57 80 47 68 56 84 65))
               ("Emp2" (57 69 57 84 87 71 77 69 61 48))
               ("Emp3" (46 47 61 65 81 64 40 77 51 78))
               ("Emp4" (70 68 89 41))
               ("Emp5" (45 48 74 83 40 44 70 85 98 86))))

;; [Listof Number] -> Number
;; sums every number in l
(define (lsum l)
  (apply + l))

;; a recursive version, if you want:
(define (lsum-rec l)
  (if (empty? l)
      0
      (+ (first l) (lsum-rec (rest l)))))


;; you can map lsum on the [Listof Number] part of the team
(define (emp-sum team)
  (map (λ (empl) (list (first empl) (lsum (second empl)))) team))

(check-equal? (emp-sum team)
              '(("Emp1" 514) ("Emp2" 680) ("Emp3" 610) ("Emp4" 268) ("Emp5" 673)))

(define (team-sum team)
  (lsum (map second (emp-sum team))))

(check-equal? (team-sum team)
              2745)
```

Comment: Would this work if the values were changed? Would want to print out the values dynamically

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in this part:

```
(first team)
```

The first team is a *list* of two elements, an identifier and a sublist, and we want to add all the elements in that sublist. Here's how:

```
(define (getEmpTotals team)
  (if (empty? team)
      0
      (+ (apply + (first (rest (first team))))
         (getEmpTotals (rest team)))))
```

The `(first (rest (first team)))` part can be simplified as `(cadar team)`. And `(apply + ...)` is adding all the elements in the sublist.

As a different alternative, we can use higher-order procedures to write a more idiomatic solution:

```
(define (getEmpTotals team)
  (foldl (λ (t acc) (+ (apply + (cadr t)) acc))
         0
         team))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(getEmpTotals team)
=> 2745
```